# Meteor listen to mongo db updates

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am trying to create a game with meteor. Since many people told me to use mongo db (because it's vanilla, fast and reactive) I realised, that I would need to "listen" to the mongo db update, in order to be able to respond to the recived code, and make changes to the DOM.

Can I use the [Meteor Trackers](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/tracker) like this:

```js
var handle = Tracker.autorun(function () {
  handleEvent(
    collection.find({}, {sort: {$natural : 1}, limit: 1 }) // find last element in collection
  );
});
```

Comment: what you are looking for is the `observe` and `observerChanges` functions of cursors. See here: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe You could use the tracker, but I think observing the cursor is more scalable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `observe` and `observerChanges` functions of cursors. See here: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe

You could use the tracker, but I think observing the cursor is more scalable.

Since in your example you seem to be interested only in responding to the last added object, here is a skeleton on how you could do that with `observeChanges`:

```
var cursor = Collection.find();
cursor.observeChanges({
    added: function(id, object) {
       // This code runs when a new object "object" was added to collection.
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks like I was a little late with my answer. But still thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`cursor.observer()` seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

My resolution looks like this:

```
collection.find({}).observe({
  addedAt: function (document, atIndex, before) {
    handleEvent(
      document
    );
  }
});
```

<del>The only "problem" I realised is, that while testing it seemed like the event got fired twice. (but htat will probably go into another thread. sometime soon)</del>

(This is <del>(I think)</del> because of the latency compensation, where the object gets inserted in the client db, then the server executes his method, and then sends the new collection to the client, where the "added" event is triggered again. right?)

Answer (score -1):

I think Tracker.autorun only work for client, so your code can run on the client but not server. May be if you want to update your client side collection, you can autorun subscription instead.